# Regarding OEIS and integer sequences

Tags: oeis, integer-sequences

The [OEIS](https://oeis.org/), a collection that was begun by Neil J. A. Sloane, is an online databse of over $360,000$ integer sequences.  Now, suppose I have an integer sequence, say, $a_1, a_2, a_3, ...$ I look for this sequence in OEIS. The sequence is unavailable.

Maybe there are two sequences in OEIS  such that my sequence is a sum of those two sequences.

How can I search if my sequence is a sum of two sequences in OEIS?

Comment: You might try to [download the database](https://oeis.org/wiki/Welcome#Compressed_Versions) and do what you want on your computer but I don't believe you will be able to search what you want (decomposition as a sum of two sequences) more efficiently than brute force (maybe I'm wrong?).

Comment: I think it should be considered that OEIS , although it is very popular because it contains a huge number of sequences , has some issues. The status "approved" means "approved by the author", doublechecks are usually not done and errors are therefore always possible , although I very rarely found one (I slightly remember some entry concerning the number of groups). Additionally , I heard from some member that entries cannot be removed.

Comment: Concerning your actual question, I agree the above comment , and also it will not be efficient to search for two sequences whose sum is the given one.

Comment: @Peter—Approved means "approved by an editor", not by the author. (Although in some cases Neil Sloane approves sequences that he records from journal articles and this sort of thing.) Errors aren't too common, but they occur from time to time, especially in sequences that aren't referenced very much. [Entries can be removed, and they're recorded.](https://oeis.org/wiki/Deleted_sequences) although sometimes they're [left in the database](https://oeis.org/search?q=keyword%3Adead) so that journal references to them don't rot.

Comment: "Sloane" is not the name (nor a nickname) of the database, it is just the surname of its founder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OEIS has a feature called "[Superseeker](https://oeis.org/ol.html)" that is supposed to do just this sort of thing.

Also, as [Idéophage suggests](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4252630/regarding-oeis-and-integer-sequences#comment8842001_4252630), you can download the database to your computer and write a program that checks if your sequence is the sum of any existing sequences.